# Why can't the ordering of my DataTable be turned off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I can't turn off ordering. In fact, I can't change anything with the JavaScript code. Here's what I have:

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,r-2.0.2,sc-1.4.1/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,r-2.0.2,sc-1.4.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable()( {"ordering": "false"} );
    } );
</script>
```

```css
#mainProduct {

    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: solid white;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.card-container {
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left: 15px;">

  <!-- Product listings -->

  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" text-align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <!-- T-REX COFFEE -->
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366446">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/BrcRPOF9yezzdQA7qI0GGt9CQpA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/0cc5/th/pre/i/2016/059/a/a/1_t_rex_coffee_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfftx.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back">
                <p id="description">What better way to show you love coffee than with a prehistoric predator!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- TAFFY CAT BATUSI -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366550">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/_WQLrq--RN0K8ixtplOOzyahVko=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/aefe/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/7/14_taffycat_batusi_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg15.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description">What's better than Taffy Cat doing the Batusi? Taffy cat doing the Batusi on a t-shirt!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- SMILEY CONVERSE -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/kxTUWMz6TsfYVFSd_YSycsGW70I=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/bbd1/th/pre/i/2016/059/8/f/36_smiley_red_shoe_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg7p.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description">Smiley red shoe. Because ... shoe!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <!-- I'M BUFF -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/UCKBK6KyJzceGbuB8szw-ucEZ2Y=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/a544/th/pre/i/2016/059/e/9/18_buff_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfq5g.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- Curvy -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/Lljv-RDFIKZCRuTf-GAxc0_BI0o=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/da78/th/pre/i/2016/059/7/c/19_curvy_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfqau.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- Love female&female -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t01.deviantart.net/hGoyHjNSwG-HMyz4tBPYyWBJnD8=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/bc6e/th/pre/i/2016/059/c/8/42_love3_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo91.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <!-- love male&male -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t04.deviantart.net/cgbfKcYI8e56QSdswTVHPMG8LOI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre12/3e14/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/b/41_love2_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo4w.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- 420 Deadpool -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/yUSAlWXmNVP8S_eBilkJrQVe3h0=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/9557/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/d/26_420pool_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfltp.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- Super Taffy Cat -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/_ynkAcDVU3UrjIgmeUhz49Itxzs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre10/c388/th/pre/i/2016/059/5/c/15_taffycat14_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfmhe.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <!-- Taffy Cat book -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- Prop of 420 -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- All that list -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
        <div class="card-container">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
            </div>
            <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <!-- Taffy Cat book -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- Prop of 420 -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>

        <!-- All that list -->
        <td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
          <div class="card-container">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
              </div>
              <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated, been looking at it, messing with it so much it's driving me crazy. Note I'm fairly new to DataTables so sorry in advance if it's a really dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization should look like this `$('#example').DataTable({"ordering": false});`. Lower case d, like `datatable` works as well.

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,r-2.0.2,sc-1.4.1/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jqc-1.12.0,dt-1.10.11,b-1.1.2,r-2.0.2,sc-1.4.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({"ordering": false});  
} );

</script>
```

```css
#mainProduct {
    
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: solid white;
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.card-container {
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left: 15px;">
<!-- Product listings -->

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" text-align="center">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
<!--T-REX COFFEE-->
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366446">
   <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
     <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/BrcRPOF9yezzdQA7qI0GGt9CQpA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/0cc5/th/pre/i/2016/059/a/a/1_t_rex_coffee_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfftx.png">
     </div>
    <div class="side back">
     <p id="description">What better way to show you love coffee than with a prehistoric predator!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</a>
</td>

<!--TAFFY CAT BATUSI-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="http://www.cafepress.com/mizoo/13366550">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/_WQLrq--RN0K8ixtplOOzyahVko=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/aefe/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/7/14_taffycat_batusi_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg15.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">What's better than Taffy Cat doing the Batusi? Taffy cat doing the Batusi on a t-shirt!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

<!--SMILEY CONVERSE-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t12.deviantart.net/kxTUWMz6TsfYVFSd_YSycsGW70I=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/bbd1/th/pre/i/2016/059/8/f/36_smiley_red_shoe_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfg7p.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Smiley red shoe. Because ... shoe!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<!--I'M BUFF-->

<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/UCKBK6KyJzceGbuB8szw-ucEZ2Y=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre09/a544/th/pre/i/2016/059/e/9/18_buff_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfq5g.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Curvy-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/Lljv-RDFIKZCRuTf-GAxc0_BI0o=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/da78/th/pre/i/2016/059/7/c/19_curvy_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfqau.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Because thinking you are something is half the journey of being something ...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Love female&female-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t01.deviantart.net/hGoyHjNSwG-HMyz4tBPYyWBJnD8=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/bc6e/th/pre/i/2016/059/c/8/42_love3_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo91.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<!--love male&male-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t04.deviantart.net/cgbfKcYI8e56QSdswTVHPMG8LOI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre12/3e14/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/b/41_love2_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfo4w.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description">Celebrate love and diversity!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--420 Deadpool-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t08.deviantart.net/yUSAlWXmNVP8S_eBilkJrQVe3h0=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre01/9557/th/pre/i/2016/059/2/d/26_420pool_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfltp.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Super Taffy Cat-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t07.deviantart.net/_ynkAcDVU3UrjIgmeUhz49Itxzs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre10/c388/th/pre/i/2016/059/5/c/15_taffycat14_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfmhe.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<!--Taffy Cat book-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t02.deviantart.net/D6FyR9Ku_FWdtRRSJQSH90Fy9z4=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre11/5f3a/th/pre/i/2016/059/6/4/13_taffycat12_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfng8.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--Prop of 420-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/Br5zZ0fwMNx3Tyebl0HT7TjB9GI=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre06/32ac/th/pre/i/2016/059/9/4/24_propertyof420_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfope.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
<!--All that list-->
<td id="mainProduct"><a href="">
<div class="card-container">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="side"><img src="http://t09.deviantart.net/ugkgkxMIkDWBjB-SEKEJDpHE4Zs=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre02/00e6/th/pre/i/2016/059/b/c/43__checklist_by_mizoodesigns-d9tfkdq.png">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"><p id="description"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```